# Lightning Documentation - Method reference with examples

Tags: lightning, documentation, reference

Is there anyway I can look for all the methods available under the components and how to use it? Like, what are the methods available under **component**, **event** objects?

EDIT:
I need methods under component objects like Component, event for which I cannot get method list similar to $A through browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Go to Chrome Browser
- Right click on web page area click Inspect
  Element
- Go to Console tab in split window
- Type $A in console input

You should get all methods in dropdown as shown in image below:

[image]

[Aura documentation](http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#reference?topic=api:$A) should be helpful in understanding and see all methods. However, not all methods may not be supported in Salesforce.

[image]

Comment: Can you please get me such reference for Component and event?

Comment: @Vignex In answer link of the documentation is given. It has all required information.